# Find the fundamental period

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

How do I find the fundamental period of this function?

$$y = \sin x + \cos(1,01x)$$

I know that the fundamental period of  $\sin x$ is $2\pi$ and the fundamental period of $cos(1,01x)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{1,01}$, but what can I do then?

Comment: solve $n 2\pi = m \frac{2\pi}{1,01}$ for minimal values of $n,m$